# Facebook Connect Safari cannot open page

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, facebook

HI I am using faceobok connect and the official Facebook tutorial below:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/
Now when I simulate it it goes to Facebook then it sais something about the app and you press done. When I press done it sais safari cannot open the page because it is an invalid address. Here is my property list:

Here is my code:

```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
return [facebook handleOpenURL:url]; 
}

// For iOS 4.2+ support
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
 sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
return [facebook handleOpenURL:url]; 
}

  - (void)fbDidLogin {
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
[defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
[defaults synchronize];

  }

  -(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:  (NSInteger)buttonIndex       {

if (buttonIndex == 0) {
    // facebook
    facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"387500177929927" andDelegate:self];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
        && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
        facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
        facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    }

    if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
        [facebook authorize:nil];
    }
}
 }
```

Property list:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"            
   "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
   <array>
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>387500177929927</string>
    </array>
</dict>
  </array>
  </plist>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your CFBundleURLSchemes key looks wrong, for that app it should be `fb387500177929927`, not `387500177929927`

From [the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#implementsso)

> Create a new row named URL types with a single item, URL Schemes, 
>       containing a single value, fbYOUR_APP_ID (the literal characters fb 
>       followed by your app ID).